# Block metabox - No expanding, no moving around

Tags: metabox, javascript

I would like to make metaboxes as fixed elements, removing the expand function and the drag-and-drop function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Deregistering the postbox script seemed a little bit drastic and as mentioned the "Edit" button for the permalink slug does not work as expected anymore.

I actually came up another method which uses filters from Wordpress and the functionality of the jQuery UI sortable plugin allowing to cancel the sort when it is issued from specific element(s) through the [cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/sortable/#option-cancel) option.

### Context

Wordpress 3.4.2 uses [jQuery UI 1.8.20](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/sortable/). Here's the initialization code that is used in postbox.js (I've stripped down the not relevant options):

```
a(".meta-box-sortables").sortable({
    ...
    connectWith: ".meta-box-sortables",
    items: ".postbox",
    handle: ".hndle",
    ...
});
```

So the plugin creates a sortable list for elements `.postbox`. The sort is issued with the child element `.hndle`.

### Solution

1. **Adding classes to the `.postbox` elements**

   Wordpress provides a filter hook to customize the css classes added to the postboxes:

   ```
   postbox_classes_{page}_{id}
   ```

   `{page}` is the page the metabox is displayed on
   `{id}`is the metabox id

   So if I have a metabox with id "_movie_details_metabox" applied for a custom post type called "movie_type", you can do this:

   ```
   function metabox_not_sortable($classes) {
       $classes[] = 'not-sortable';
       return $classes;
   }
   add_filter('postbox_classes_movie_type__movie_details_metabox', 'metabox_not_sortable');
   ```
2. **Alter jquery ui sortable instance**

   Then you can insert a footer script in the admin area to alter the sortable instance to cancel the sort event if it is issued through the `.hndle` element from a postbox with the added css class `not-sortable`:

```php
    <?php
    add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts','my_admin_print_footer_scripts',99);
    function my_admin_print_footer_scripts()
    {
        ?><script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
            jQuery(function($)
            {
                $(".meta-box-sortables")
                    // define the cancel option of sortable to ignore sortable element
                    // for boxes with '.not-sortable' css class
                    .sortable('option', 'cancel', '.not-sortable .hndle, :input, button')
                    // and then refresh the instance
                    .sortable('refresh');
            });
        /* ]]> */</script><?php
    }
```

Postboxes with the css class `.not-sortable` cannot be sorted anymore, the other ones still can.

Comment: hmhm, I got "cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization"...though I increased the 99 number

Answer (score 1):

[deregister](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) the 'postbox' script. Place the following in your theme's `functions.php` or in a plugin file.

```
function dereg() {
  wp_deregister_script('postbox');
}
add_action('admin_init','dereg');
```

I did a very cursory test and it does stop the dragging and the folding, and I don't notice anything broken.

The little folding arrow still show up but that is CSS not Javascript. If it bothers you you can kill it with:

```
function acss() {
echo '<style type="text/css">.postbox:hover .handlediv,
.stuffbox:hover .handlediv {display: none;
}</script>';
}
add_action('admin_head','acss');
```

Comment: It seems to break the "Edit" button for changing the permalink slug.

Comment: It just kills the inline Javascript editing. You can still edit via the 'Slug' meta_box. It is annoying that that function is mixed into the same script, though.

Comment: I have spent some time trying a number of different things and have not been able to find any other way to prevent the dragging and folding. I keep thinking there must be another way but...

Answer (score 0):

To answer half of the question, this is how you remove folding in your custom post type:

**php for including css for post.php edit page**

```
function enqueue_your_custom_adminstuff(){
    wp_enqueue_style('mycustomstyle', plugins_url('/css/mycustomstyle.css', __FILE__),array(),filemtime(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."/css/mycustomstyle.css")); 
    /* Note: I use filemtime to prevent caching the old style version */   
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_your_custom_adminstuff');
```

**mycustomstyle.css**

```
.post-type-yourcustomposttypeslug .postbox.closed .handlediv .toggle-indicator:before{
    content: "\f142"!important; /* the arrow */
}
.post-type-yourcustomposttypeslug .postbox.closed .inside{
    display:block;
}
```